# How can I get Excel to stop using the letter "E" in text data as a mathematical function in excel formulas that access that text data?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

I have this `P-1-A6E100` as a the data in my `binId` column. 
This is read as first floor, module A, aisle 6, shelf E, slot 100.
I have a formula I made to pull out the aisle number if it is 1, 2, or 3 digits long:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID([@binId],6,3))),VALUE(MID([@binId],6,3)),IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID([@binId],6,2))),VALUE(MID([@binId],6,2)),VALUE(MID([@binId],6,1))))
```

Any time there is an "E" in the shelf, it causes an incorrect result for the aisle number. In this case: "60."

For now, I've just decided to substitute out the "E" for a placeholder character, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way?

Comment: And yes, I tried formatting the cells in all sorts of ways. The formula itself is where there is an issue.

Comment: It will be interpreting the characters "6E1" as [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) for 6 * 10^1, i.e. 60. I guess that the bin numbers are not changeable as regard to their format, so you will need to devise a better way of parsing out the parts of the bin numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should pull out 1, 2, or 3 numbers for you aisle number.  Basically it is checking where the character after the first character of the ailse number is a number or text.  Measuring the length of your number.  based on the results it evaluates that chunk as text.  if you need it as a number either put -- in front of the function that returns it as text or multiply the function by 1.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(--MID([@binId],7,1)),IF(ISNUMBER(--MID([@binId],8,1)),MID([@binId],6,3),MID([@binId],6,2)),MID([@binId],6,1))
```